# How to return an instance of a trait?

Tags: rust

I'm working on [a SQL migration tool](https://github.com/Keats/dbmigrate).
Right now I only support Postgresql but i'd like to add Mysql, etc.

I have the following trait that drivers need to implement:

```
pub trait Driver {
    fn ensure_migration_table_exists(&self);
    fn remove_migration_table(&self);
    fn get_current_number(&self) -> i32;
    fn set_current_number(&self, number: i32);
    fn migrate(&self, migration: String, number: i32) -> MigrateResult<()>;
}
```

I want to make a function `get_driver` which would have the following conceptual definition `fn get_driver(url: &str) -> MigrateResult<Driver>`.

Based on a discussion on IRC a month ago, this is apparently impossible to do. My previous best guess fails like so:

```
fn get_driver<T: Driver + Sized>(url: &str) -> MigrateResult<T>

expected `core::result::Result<T, errors::MigrateError>`,
found `core::result::Result<drivers::pg::Postgres, errors::MigrateError>`
```

(expected type parameter,
    found struct `drivers::pg::Postgres`) [E0308]

Is there any way to work around that?

The [full code is available](https://github.com/Keats/dbmigrate/tree/master/src/drivers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function:

```
fn get_driver<T: Driver + Sized>(url: &str) -> MigrateResult<T>
```

`T` is a *type parameter*. It is chosen by the caller of the function.

It looks like you want to a return a different type based on the value of `url`. But Rust is statically-typed: the type of any expression at any point in the code needs to be known at compile-time. (Even generics get specialized to concrete types when they’re used.) The way to deal with this is to use trait objects:

For example, in:

```
fn get_driver(url: &str) -> MigrateResult<Box<Driver>>
```

`Box<Driver>` is a *fat pointer* made of a pointer to the value and a pointer to the *virtual call table* for the a concrete type that implements the `Driver` trait. That vtable contains pointers to the code for each method of the trait.

Read more at http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seems it's expecting a trait now though, not a trait object:

 expected `core::result::Result<Box<drivers::Driver + 'static>, errors::MigrateError>`,
    found `core::result::Result<Box<drivers::pg::Postgres>, errors::MigrateError>`
(expected trait drivers::Driver,
    found struct `drivers::pg::Postgres`) [E0308]
src/drivers/mod.rs:17     pg::Postgres::new(url).map(|d| Box::new(d))

Comment: Sometimes the type inference figures it out and this can be implicit, but you may need to coerce explicitly your concrete box to a trait object: `Box::new(d) as Box<Driver>`.