# rust: expected type parameter, found struct

Tags: generics, struct, types, rust

I have written functions that calcuate some datetime (from chrono) for various TimeZone's T. The functions differ mostly only in the returned value's type `DateTime<Utc>`, `DateTime<Local>` etc.
I am wondering if it is possible to generalize this using generics with something like

`fn event<T: TimeZone>() -> DateTime<T>`

instead of separate functions

`fn event_local() -> DateTime<Local>`

`fn event_local() -> DateTime<Utc>`

...

Trying to put it in the generalized version, I get the error 
"expected type parameter, found struct"
I understand the error, but I'd like to know if there is a way to circumvent it since it is tedious to implement multiple functions with almost identical logic.

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::{TimeZone, DateTime, Local};

fn event() -> DateTime<Local> {
    Local.ymd(2019,8,13).and_hms(17, 30, 0)
}

fn event_utc() -> DateTime<Local> {
    Utc.ymd(2019,8,13).and_hms(17, 30, 0)
}
```

works, while

```
fn event<T: TimeZone>() -> DateTime<T> {
    Local.ymd(2019,8,13).and_hms(17, 30, 0)
}
```

doesn't compile with the above error.

Looking at question [How to return an instance of a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708584/how-to-return-an-instance-of-a-trait), it is suggested to use a Box, but I am not able to figure out how to do it. I'd appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood correctly, you want to create a generic function to call `ymd()` for different time zones.

Here is a working example of a generic function for this case:

```
fn event<T: TimeZone>(s: T) -> DateTime<T> {
    s.ymd(2019,8,13).and_hms(17, 30, 0)
}
```

To call the function, use:

```
event::<Local>(Local);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed!